# Can my work place access my private google account

Tags: email

I received the below message. My view is not to respond as the message is incorrect.  I'm not even sure why it states my personal account is registered against work email address.

It says :

> We are aware that a personal Google account has been created and
>   registered against your Work email address.
>
> In preparation for the move to G Suite we need to transfer ownership
>   of this account so that your new G Suite account can be created.
>
> You will shortly receive an email with a message similar to the
>   screenshot attached asking you to accept or reject the transfer of
>   this account. Please action this as soon as possible so we can start
>   to create your new G Suite account.
>
> Please note that when you accept the transfer you will loose access to
>   the account until your new G Suite account is assigned as part of your
>   team's move to G Suite. If this temporary loss of access is going to
>   cause a problem due to the account being critical for your work them
>   please let us know.

Comment: If you copy/pasted the text from the email, then it looks like a phishing attempt

Comment: I agree @schroeder, looks like a phishing attempt

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169782/is-there-any-definitive-way-to-tell-if-an-email-is-a-phishing-attempt

Comment: There is no such thing as a "personal google account."

Answer (score 1):

This is a phishing email. Ignore it, and certainly don't transfer anything if you get a follow-up. If your work has a "phishing@" or "soc@" email address or similar, report it to them. You probably aren't the only one who got it.